# List overview of multilanguage data

Tags: tables

I have a dataset with the following record definition, each of the translation property-sets are optional but at least one should be entered.

- Product

  - id
  - price
  - translations

    - english

      - name
      - description
    - french

      - name
      - description
    - dutch

      - name
      - description
    - ...

What is considered best practice when you need to show this dataset in a grid where the name of the record should be present, the problem i have is that the name could be in english, dutch or french and that might confuse users.

In the table view below the name property of 1 and 2 are english, 3 and 4 french and 5 dutch. I'm afraid this will confuse users alot thus i'm looking for a way to make records easier distinguisable in the table overview. Perhaps by prefixing the language to the name `[en]Oranges` for example. I'm wondering if there are any other best practices or solutions for this?

```
ID      Name            Price       Actions
------------------------------------------------------
1       Oranges         $20         Edit / Delete
2       Apples          $10         Edit / Delete
3       Poires          $5          Edit / Delete
4       Cerises         $10         Edit / Delete
5       Banaan          $3          Edit / Delete
```

Comment: Chris - Who are your users and what are their general characteristics? The more I look at this the more I'm wanting to know who uses the table.

Answer (score 2):

Why not add an own column for the language? That way users could filter data by language if they don't need to see but a specific language(s).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you can even display the grid you showed? I'm asking, because it has one column (Name) that takes values from different fields every time - Trans>Eng>Name, Trans>Fr>Name, Trans>Du>Name. How would you know which field to display each time? I suppose it's possible, like most things in software, but it's going to be some hack or another... But I'm out of my depth here, just wanted to make sure you're aware of the problem.

In terms of solutions - the way I see it, you need two separate columns for each language. Since it can be a lot, a more elegant solution may be a nested grid, something like this:

```
  ID      Eng. Name     Eng. Description       Price     Actions
--------------------------------------------------------------
-  1       Apples        Nice green ones        $20       Edit/Delete
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Fr. Name       Fr. Description     Du. Name     Du. Description   |   
  | ===============================================================   | 
  | Les Pommes     Nice vertes          Appels       Mooie groene     |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------
+ 2       Oranges        Nice orange ones       $10       Edit/Delete    
+ 3       Pears          Nice soft  ones        $5        Edit/Delete
+ 4       Cherries       Nice red ones          $10       Edit/Delete
```

You can see a jquery example [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), if you go to Advanced>Subgrid.